# Dynamic resistance of diode

Tags: diodes

I have been given a circuit and asked to find the voltage across the diode (both the DC and AC parts).

[image]

I believe the right approach is the ignore the ac source initially and find the *I<sub>D</sub>Q*. I know there is 0.6 V across the diode so I found *I<sub>D</sub>Q* to be 14.4 V/1 kΩ = 0.0144 A by analyzing the resistor.

I know there is an equation for dynamic resistance: $$r_d = \frac{nV_T}{I_DQ}$$ I am given *n* = 1 and *V<sub>T</sub>* = 26 mV so I get r<sub>d</sub> = 1.86 Ω. I interpret this as: in this setup, because the ac signal is small and the diode will always be forward biased, we can effectively treat the diode as a resistor of value *r<sub>d</sub>*.

But if I look at the voltage across the diode at the Q point using the voltage divider: $$V_D = \frac{15r_d}{r_d + 1\mathrm{\ k\Omega}} = 0.028\mathrm{\ V}$$
But it should equal 0.6 V. Have I done something wrong in my calculations? Or am I interpreting *r<sub>d</sub>* incorrectly?

I know I haven't finished the given question yet, but I thought I would make this check and it would show me if I am on the right track or if I have already made a mistake.

Comment: The dynamic resistance you are using is relevant to when supplying with an AC source - it doesn't give you the full picture on DC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your misunderstanding is around how the small-signal AC characteristics combine with the large DC characteristics. If V<sub>D</sub> is the DC (ie: average) voltage across the diode, you've already assumed that to be 0.6V.

The value r<sub>d</sub> represents only the *incremental* resistance of the diode if you add or subtract a small amount of current (ie: add or subtract a small amount of voltage at the input, like 0.1 cos(wt) ). So you use r<sub>d</sub> to calculate the voltage resulting only from that small change in current.

So:

*v<sub>in</sub>* = 0.1 cos(wt), and the resulting small signal effect across the diode is:

$$v_d = \frac{v_{in} r_d}{r_d + 1\mathrm{\ k\Omega}}$$

and *V<sub>diode_total</sub> = V<sub>D</sub> + v<sub>d</sub>*

Comment: I agree to the above comments. Knowing that for each non-linear device you have to discriminate between STATIC and DYNAMIC resistances it is clear that you are not allowed to add both parts. For a diode, the dynamic resistance is the inverse of the SLOPE of the Id=f(Vd) curve (at the Q point) and the static resistance is the inverse slope of the line between the the origin and the Q point.

Comment: That clears it up! I went ahead with my calculations and ended up with the total output voltage across the diode to be \$0.6+1.8*10^-4*cos(wt)\$ which seems consistent with your explanation. However, I have simulated this circuit on PSPICE and it gives me an output of \$0.7436+4*10^-4*cos(wt)\$. Why does the simulation show a different output to what I have derived (I'm certain the simulator is correctly set up)? Is it because of assumptions during the derivation?

Comment: Yes - of course. There is - at first - a very rough assumption of 0.6 V (which coud be also 0.65...0.7V) and - secondly - the formula for the dynamic part of the diode resistance does not yet consider the ohmic part of the Id=f(Vd) characteristic. As you probably know, this curve is NOT a pure exponential function. And all these "parasitics" are included in the simulation model.

Comment: I am curious how the simulation arrived at a V_D of 0.7436V at only 14mA. Regardless, that moves you to a steeper part of the diode's V vs I curve, so that small changes of current (here: input voltage) cause larger changes in v_d, as your simulation reported.

Comment: @gwideman I also thought 0.7436V was too high as we have been taught that it is somewhere between 0.6 and 0.7 but I have triple checked all of the component values in the simulator...

Comment: I simulated the 1N4149 with 14.4mA - and the result was Vd=0.744 Volts. I think, this value  shows the influence of the ohmic part of the device resistance.

Comment: For signals diodes, 1N4148 would be a more widely-used choice rather than 1N4149 (check distributors to see how many variants of each there are!). And it does appear that these diodes' V_f for 14mA is higher than the rule-of-thumb 0.6 or 0.7V. If you try with 1N4001 you will probably get closer to what your calculations estimate.

Comment: It tells use to use 1N4148, which I did.

Comment: I don't understand how the total diode voltage is 0.6+1.8∗10−4∗cos(wt) part + the cos part. So this means the voltage across the diode oscillates around a base voltage of 0.6V. But this means the diode is off half of the time. That would mean that half of the time, the diode voltage should be the input voltage (approx 15V). but this isn't shown in the diode voltage equation, nor does it happen in the simulator. Have I got the wrong equation for the total diode voltage? Surely it shouldn't drop below 0.6V. How could the diode turn off when the input is 14.9V?!